# Training a CNTK model in Python with np arrays as inputs

Tags: python, numpy, cntk

I've been attempting to re-write a simple classifier with CNTK. But all the examples I've come across use the built-in Reader with input map and my data needs to be heavily modified once read so I haven't been able to use what most of the examples demonstrate as the data loading method. I came across code on [here](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/Manual_How_to_feed_data.html) that seems to show how to use straight np arrays for training, but it doesn't seem to actually train anything.

Minimum working example showing the issue:

```
import cntk as C
import numpy as np
from cntk.ops import relu
from cntk.layers import Dense, Convolution2D

outputs = 10

input_var = C.input_variable((7, 19, 19), name='features')
label_var = C.input_variable((outputs))

epochs = 20
minibatchSize = 100

cc = C.layers.Convolution2D((3,3), 64, activation=relu)(input_var)
net = C.layers.Dense(outputs)(cc)

loss = C.cross_entropy_with_softmax(net, label_var)

learner = C.adam(net.parameters, 0.0018, 0.9, minibatch_size=minibatchSize)

progressPrinter = C.logging.ProgressPrinter(tag='Training', num_epochs=epochs)

for i in range(epochs):
    X = np.zeros((minibatchSize, 7, 19, 19), dtype=np.float32)
    Y = np.ones((minibatchSize, outputs), dtype=np.float32)

    train_summary = loss.train((X, Y), parameter_learners=[learner], callbacks=[progressPrinter])
```

Sample output:

```
Learning rate per 100 samples: 0.0018
Finished Epoch[1 of 20]: [Training] loss = 2.302410 * 100, metric = 0.00% * 100 0.835s (119.8 samples/s);
Finished Epoch[2 of 20]: [Training] loss = 0.000000 * 0, metric = 0.00% * 0 0.003s (  0.0 samples/s);
Finished Epoch[3 of 20]: [Training] loss = 0.000000 * 0, metric = 0.00% * 0 0.001s (  0.0 samples/s);
```

There's probably a really obvious reason this is happening, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any ideas on how to remedy this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the solution is actually really simple, you can create an input dictionary easily without the reader. Here is the full code that solves the training issue:

```
import cntk as C
import numpy as np
from cntk.ops import relu
from cntk.layers import Dense, Convolution2D

outputs = 10

input_var = C.input_variable((7, 19, 19), name='features')
label_var = C.input_variable((outputs))

epochs = 20
minibatchSize = 100

cc = C.layers.Convolution2D((3,3), 64, activation=relu)(input_var)
net = C.layers.Dense(outputs)(cc)

loss = C.cross_entropy_with_softmax(net, label_var)
pe = C.classification_error(net, label_var)    

learner = C.adam(net.parameters, 0.0018, 0.9, minibatch_size=minibatchSize)

progressPrinter = C.logging.ProgressPrinter(tag='Training', num_epochs=epochs)
trainer = C.Trainer(net, (loss, pe), learner, progressPrinter)    

for i in range(epochs):
    X = np.zeros((minibatchSize, 7, 19, 19), dtype=np.float32)
    Y = np.ones((minibatchSize, outputs), dtype=np.float32)

    trainer.train_minibatch({input_var : X, label_var : Y})

    trainer.summarize_training_progress()
```